# Error during updating the gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, nullreferenceexception

I got the below error message while updating the value on the gridview:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

And my c# code is:

```
protected void gvDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int nmbr = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    TextBox name = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("names");
    TextBox dept = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("depts");
    TextBox quantity = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("quantitys");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmds=new SqlCommand("update erbp set name ='" + name.Text + "',dept ='"+ 
              dept.Text+"',quantity='" + quantity.Text + "' where inmbr=" + nmbr , con);
    cmds.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindEmployeeDetails();
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving  you error?

Comment: A good practice is always to test if the FindControl is actually returning something.

Comment: can you tell the line number where the error originated

Comment: In addition: a) use parameterized SQL; b) use `using` statements for SQL operations to clean up resources.

Comment: the error is generated on the below line:                           SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand("update erbp set name ='" + name.Text + "',dept ='"+ dept.Text+"',quantity='" + quantity.Text + "' where inmbr=" + nmbr , con);

Comment: In addition: c) do exception handling

Comment: @ram it means that either of your controls name, dept or quantity is null.

Comment: Where you are initializing the connection object?

Comment: @Nithesh con cannot be the culprit here as it is open in the previous line. Had this been null it would have given error in the previous line.

Comment: yesterday the same is executed correctly and today only i got this error sir @EhsanUllah

Comment: @EhsanUllah. ya you are correct. declare separate variables for `name`, `quantity` and assign corresponding values and check while debugging. Or try with `Convert.ToString()` inside the query part itself and check.

Comment: @ram place your debugger over this line and see which control is null. VS compiler cannot be wrong

Comment: so i can post it answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your code to check that controls that you have assigned from gridview are not null. Do some exception handling as well.

```
protected void gvDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
  int nmbr = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
  TextBox name = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("names");
  TextBox dept = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("depts");
  TextBox quantity = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("quantitys");
  //do check that any of your controls here is not null
  if(name!=null && dept!=null && quantity !=null)
  {
      con.Open();
      SqlCommand cmds=new SqlCommand("update erbp set name ='" + name.Text + "',dept ='"+ 
          dept.Text+"',quantity='" + quantity.Text + "' where inmbr=" + nmbr , con);
      cmds.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
      GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
      BindEmployeeDetails();
  }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)       
  {
      //do exception handling here. 
  }
}
```